# Do a jQuery/ajax POST on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have an html form like this:

```
<form action="myServer.com/test.php" method="post">
...
</form>
```

When the form is submitted, the user should be redirected to myServer.com/test.php and ofc send the post data to the script. BUT at the same time (or before), I want to post the same POST data to another script "myServer.com/test2.php".

```
$.post("myServer.com/test2.php", variableWithTheFormPOSTData);
```

I tried to attach an EventListener to the form submit, but that doesn't seem to work, maybe the jquery post cant be submitted fast enough before the redirection?

I hope you can help me. :(

Comment: The API has several examples. Trying copy/pasting one, getting a feel for it, and then writing your own. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ The last example specifically grabs data from a form.

Comment: you can try jquery ajax for this purpose, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use a method with onsubmit, make sure it returns true, otherwise it won't submit.

Answer (score 0):

use a button as your submit button sothat the form doesnt get posted at the same time you click on it. And trigger the ajax function to post the data indirectly to the second page.

```
<form name="myform" action="myServer.com/test.php" method="post">
    ...
    <button onclick="doIndirectPost();"></button>
</form>
```

and in the success callback of ajax posting function trigger your form post

```
function doIndirectPost() {
    //initialize variableWithTheFormPOSTData here
    $.post("myServer.com/test2.php", variableWithTheFormPOSTData,function(success,error)    {
         //ajax post is completed now we trigger the form post to test.php
         document.myform.submit();

    });  
}
```

Comment: That sounds like a great solution!
But how do I get the post data from the form into my $.post() ?

Comment: use jquery.serialize `var variableWithTheFormPOSTData = $('#myform').serialize();` this will post as a json object so you need to use json_decode() at the php end

Comment: @andrew: json_decode()? really? they're just available as request parameters the same way.

Comment: @BalusC really? Ok, well I'll leave my comment as is so as not to make yours irrelevant

Comment: I don't really know what json is, couln't I solve this problem with something like that:

http://pastebin.com/46Z2Zg6e

and would my object "variableWithTheFormPOSTData" contain the post data in a way that $.post() would use it correctly?

Comment: @user2743803 yes, you can do it with that way, but `$('#form').serialize` will produce the same output.

Comment: @andrew: even more, it will properly URL-encode the request parameters. OP's naive approach doesn't do that anywhere, so special characters may arrive malformed/corrupted in PHP side.

Comment: I still don't understand how I'd have to use json_decode() and why it is neccessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using ajax itself, which will avoid reloading the page

```
<form id="form1">
 .....
<input type="text" name="email"/> <!--Example input text box-->
<input type="button" id="submit"/> 
</form>
```

and the jquery code

```
$("#submit").click(function()
{
$.post("myServer.com/test2.php", $("#form1").serialize());//$("#form1).serialize() will get the data in the form automatically
$.post("myServer.com/test.php", $("#form1").serialize());

});
```

`.serialize()` will automatically serialize the data from the form that is to be posted

in your server side page use this

```
<?php
parse_str($_POST['serialize'], $data);
$name  = $data["email"] 


// do your code
?>
```

Hope this helps,Thank you

Comment: yeah, I think this helps a lot!
I'll do some testings now. :)

Comment: mhh.. I don't really like it.
Is there no way to just post multiple variables in one $.post() ?
I just read somewhere, that you could go like this to get what I want: http://pastebin.com/9DxhAxEp
But how would I make this dynamic sothat I always takes all form parameters?

Comment: you could use a array of each url

Comment: @user2743803 $("form").serialize takes dynamically all the form parameters

Comment: @user2743803 your need is to send the same data to different php files

Comment: yeah, i got that, but i don't want to parse them in my php. I just want a normal POST with multiple variables and not only one that i need to parse....
You know? just like the normal form-submit does it...